# Reading a csv file in a specific pattern and storing in a map or 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, excel, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file as follows:

```
Constraint,3
Op,M1,M2,M3,A1,A2,A3,
M1,0,0,0,7,2,2,
M2,0,0,0,5,4,0,
M3,0,0,0,5,2,0,
A1,0,0,0,3,3,0,
A2,0,0,0,1,1,0,
A3,0,0,0,1,0,0,
```

Constarint = 3 implies I have M1,M2,M3(three multipliers) and A1,A2,A3(three adders).

There is a value for each cell corresponding to two of the above given operators
ex: (M1,A1) has a value 7

I have written a java code to read this file line by line but for my further coding purpose I need to read the file as follows:

```
M1 M1 0
M1 M2 0
M1 M3 0
M1 A1 7
```

and so on....

How to read the file as shown above and can i store it in a map or a 2d array ?
Since I'm fairly new to programming, Any help in this regard would be great.

Cheers and Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have tried writing a piece of code and encountered any error then include your code and error stack in the question.

Comment: I haven't written any code to read it as mentioned above. I only have the code to read a csv file line by line.

Comment: You should include whatever code you have written to depict your approach towards the problem.

Comment: Look at OpenCSV (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/). Or BeanIO (http://beanio.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by using the 2D String Array. You'll have to scan your file line by line and feed the value in the 2D Array. Later you can write a function to print out the values in the desired format.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[][] matrix = new String[7][7];

    /* Set Values */
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        matrix[i] = in.nextLine().split(",");
    }

    /* Print Function */
    for(int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            System.out.println(matrix[i][0] + " " + matrix[0][j] + " " + matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
M1 M1 0
M1 M2 0
M1 M3 0
M1 A1 7
M1 A2 2
M1 A3 2

M2 M1 0
M2 M2 0
M2 M3 0
M2 A1 5
M2 A2 4
M2 A3 0

...
```